# Update values stored in random generated keys in Firebase - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am trying to update many values of alarms such as the label, time, repeatedDays, etc. So in my app, once the user creates an alarm it will be displayed in a tableview. Once they click this alarm on the tableview, they should be able to edit the values. All of this works in the UI part, however in firebase when I save the edits that I have done to this alarm, a new alarm object is created. I would like the values for this alarm to be updated once edited(and saved), instead of adding a new alarm.

Below is the structure in Firebase of my app:

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code to show you what I have tried to do:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "save" {

            var alarmRefKey = alarmRef.key //the unique alarm key

            let displayAlarms = segue.destination as! DisplayAlarms //unwind segue destination

            if alarm != nil {//alarm is the object, so if there is an alarm, you can edit it
                print("There is already an alarm.")
                let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
                timeFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

                timePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("handler:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

                let strDate: String? = timeFormatter.string(from: timePicker.date)
                print("\(strDate!) is the time!")
                alarm?.time = strDate!
                alarm?.alarmLabel = updateLabelText.text ?? ""

                self.tableView.reloadData()

                let key = alarmRefKey

                print("\(key) is the alarm key")
                var ref: DatabaseReference
                ref = Database.database().reference()
                let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid//current user's id


//                let parameters: Any? = ["alarmLabel": updateLabelText.text!, "alarmTime": strDate!, "userID": currentUserID!, "repeatedDays": weekdaysSelected]

                //where I am having trouble.
                //updating values in the alarm associated with this key.
                ref.child("alarms").child(key).updateChildValues(["alarmLabel": updateLabelText.text!, "alarmTime": strDate!, "userID": currentUserID!, "repeatedDays": weekdaysSelected])

            }
```

Comment: why don't you try saving the AutogeneratedChild.key in Database as UID  ? and when you need to update values in DB . just first check the DB with Alarm id get its snapshot and get the UID from there and update values using UID you had received from Snapshot ? if required I can show you a small Demo for it

Comment: @iOSGeek I would very much appreciate it if you could write a small demo for it.

Comment: okay will update till EOD

Comment: hi can I ask you few questions I tried your snippet in my code project and my values are being updated as per required and no new object is being created can you please share your code if possible? and as you said a new alarm is being created is it in database[created here and in tableView too] or in tableView [like created here but not in database] ? and must check the key by putting breakpoint that key you are referring is right or different than the present key